# mysql query formatting in email

Tags: shell, email, mysql

I have the following query in shell script:

```
mysql -e "use hive; select DISTINCT TAB.DB_NAME, TAB.TABLE_NAME from 
TABLE_PARAMS INNER JOIN TAB ON TABLE_PARAMS.TBL_ID = TAB.TBL_ID 
where PARAM_KEY = 'numRows'" -u root -p$Pass
```

If I run this on the command line, the formatting is great. However when I email the results using

```
| mail -s "Missing compute stats" example@example.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Its all over the place. Is there an easy way to format the results in the email?
What I have tried: putting \G at the end of a query which works okay, but I'd rather keep it in vertical format.

Thank you

EDIT: Here is the result in my email

```
DB_NAME TABLE_NAME
customer_touch  tbldatelookup
customer_touch_archive_bb   bb_comm_camphist_ltd
customer_touch_archive_bb   bb_comm_camphist033114
customer_touch_archive_bb   bb_ed_camphist
customer_touch_archive_bb   camphist
customer_touch_archive_bb   cd_drop
```

What I want to see:

```
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| DB_NAME                         | TABLE_NAME                  |
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| customer_touch                  | tbldatelookup               |
| customer_touch_archive_bb       | bb_comm_chist_ltd           |
| customer_touch_archive_bb       | st_cla_sa                   |
| customer_touch_archive_bb       | st_cla_a                    |
| customer_touchpoint_archive_stg | tier_r_prod_h27             |
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: If you view the email using an editor that can present the email body using a fixed-width font (like a console uses) what do you see?

Comment: @datUser please see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--table` or `-t` with the `mysql` client:

```
mysql -t -D hive -u root -p"$Pass" \
    -e "SELECT DISTINCT TAB.DB_NAME, TAB.TABLE_NAME
        FROM TABLE_PARAMS
        INNER JOIN TAB ON TABLE_PARAMS.TBL_ID = TAB.TBL_ID 
        WHERE PARAM_KEY = 'numRows'" |
mail -s etc. etc.
```

(By the way, isn't that SQL a bit wonky? Where's `TAB` coming from?)

From the manual:

> `--table`, `-t`
>
> Display output in table format. This is the default for interactive
>              use, but can be used to produce table output in batch mode.

Comment: TAB is the name of the table. Now im getting: ERROR 1059 (42000): Identifier name 'select DISTINCT..........' is too long. I'm confused, its shorter than it was before. Ive also edited my code, so you can tell where TAB is coming from.

Comment: @user3508766 What's the exact command you're using and what is the exact error message?